# How to query for my recent work items

Tags: tfs

The closest I was able to come up with is this:

```
(State = Closed or Assigned To != [me]) and Changed By Was Ever [me] and State Changed Date >= @Today - 7
```

That produces number of false positives on items that still being worked in QA or being touched by people handling merges. All I need is the items I touched in the last 7 days. This would be a trivial SQL to write, but TFS query UI doesn't seem to be flexible enough for this...

Comment: If you group `Change By Was Ever [me] and State Changed Date >= @Today - 7` does that do what you need?

Comment: All I was missing was "Changed By *Was Ever* [Me].  That plus Changed Date > @Today - 7 was all I needed.  Isn't that truly your recent items?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Cube to find out who has changed a work item in the past.

If you use the "Work Item Changeset" perspective you can create a pivot table in Excel by Work Item Title and Changed By and filter on the Changed Date for the last 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the work items in a sprint that were assigned to you ever and have current state closed or resolved. Please note that the state clauses are grouped.

[image]